# Finding Maximum Mod

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given a set of numbers, say $x=\{1,2,3\}$, how can I find the maximum $m$ such that $x_i\bmod m =x_j\bmod m$, where $i$ and $j$ are some indexes of the set $x$. So for $x=\{1,2,3\}$, the answer should be $1$ and for $x=\{5,2,8\}$, the answer should be $3$. I know that this won't work when say we have a set of $\{1,1,1\}$, but I am interested to knowing when it will work and how we can find the maximum $m$. Also, I am interested to know if there are any other cases where this doesn't follow.

One of the thoughts I had was to do this: $\left(\frac{x_i}{x_j}\right)\bmod b\equiv 1$, but I'm not sure if this leads anywhere.

Comment: @peterwhy No, $i$ could equal $j$

Comment: I would like some clarification. Which of the following is this question about:
$$\exists i,\exists j, x_i\bmod m = x_j\bmod m\\
\forall i,\exists j, x_i\bmod m = x_j\bmod m\\
\forall i,\forall j, x_i\bmod m = x_j\bmod m\\
$$

Comment: @peterwhy The question is about for all i and j that are valid, we need to find a maximum $m$ such that $x_i\bmod m = x_j\bmod m$. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an algorithm like the following:

m=1
While all set elements are different from 0:
if gcd($x_1,x_2,x_3$) > m then m = gcd($x_1,x_2,x_3$)
$x_1=x_1-1, x_2=x_2-1, x_3=x_3-1$

If any of the set elements is 0 then compute the gcd of the non-zero elemets, if it is greater than m then update m otherwise m is your asnwer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the $x_i \in \Bbb{Z}^+$:

Simply take $m = \sup x - \inf x$.

It is easy to prove that there are some $i,j$ such that $x_i \equiv x_ \pmod m$, namely, take $i: \sup x = x_i$ and $j: \inf x = x_j$.

It is easy to show for $k > m$ and $i \neq j$ that $x_i \neq x_j \pmod k$:
because if $x_i \equiv x_j \pmod k$ and $x_j > x_i$ then $x_j - x_i \leq m$ and
$$ x_i -x_i \equiv x_j-x_i \pmod k \\
x_j-x_i \equiv 0 \pmod k \\
x_j - x_i = nk (n>0) \\
nk \leq m
$$
but $m<k$ so that is impossible.

the other answers proposed are answering a different question:  THey assume you meant that for **all** pairs $i,j$ we have $x_i \equiv x_j \pmod m$ but your question states **some** pair $i,j$/

Comment: how do you find $\sup x - \inf x$? This is a new concept for me

Comment: What I get that sup is the maximum of the set and inf is the minimum, but for (5,2,8), 8-2=6 not 3

Answer (score 0):

Pick any element in the set, say $x_1$. Compute the set of differences:
$$y = \{n-x_1\mid n\in x\setminus \{x_1\}\}$$
Then the common divisor of all these numbers satisfy the condition, and the largest one is the GCD.

---

For example, if $x = \{5,2,8\}$, take $x_1 = 5$,
$$y = \{2-5, 8-5\} = \{-3, 3\}$$
And the GCD is $3$.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how 5,2,8 gives 3?

Comment: @user335937 edited.